# Mockito not stubbing, Error: Wanted but not invoked

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I have just started to learn testing and decided to start with Junit 5 Jupiter and Mockito

I was trying to write test case using Mockito but the test fails with error **Wanted but not invoked:**

I have tried all possible ways of injecting mock objects

- MockitoExtension
- MockitoAnnotations#openMocks
- Mockito#mock

The `verify()` method in `@Test` verifies that mock object was never invoked not even once

Here is the code:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserInfoServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserInfoServiceImpl userInfoService;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnUserInfo_whenIdIsGiven() throws Exception {
        Optional<UserInfo> userInfo = Optional.of(UserInfo.builder().email("xyz@abc.com").build());

        when(userInfoRepository.getUserInfoById(1L)).thenReturn(userInfo);

        verify(userInfoRepository).getUserInfoById(1L);
        assertEquals(userInfo,userInfoService.getUserInfo(1L));
    }
}
```

While referring other similar SO questions I learned that the main class for which test cases are written should not be mocked and to my knowledge I'm not repeating the mistake here.

Please let me know what changes I need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't call your `userInfoService`. You should do it before `verify`:

```java
@Test
public void shouldReturnUserInfo_whenIdIsGiven() throws Exception{
    Optional<UserInfo> userInfo = Optional.of(UserInfo.builder().email("xyz@abc.com").build());
    when(userInfoRepository.getUserInfoById(1L)).thenReturn(userInfo);

    UserInfo result = userInfoService.getUserInfo(1L);

    verify(userInfoRepository).getUserInfoById(1L);
    assertEquals(userInfo, result);
}
```